# How do I set the status bar from a static

Tags: c#, winforms, statusbar

I have a form (called Form1) and I have created a status strip (called toolStripProgressBar1), with a label and a progress bar. I have a function that is called when you press a button and gets some data and processes it, which works well.

I want to provide the user with some information as to its progress so I want to set the label and progress bar but I can't get it to set

```
private static async Task GetSurvey(string surid)
{
    Form1.toolStripProgressBar1.Value = 10;
```

Comment: consider using the MVP pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be a lot easier if you don't do it as static; doing the work in a method that has access to the form instance variables would make this quite trivial. Be aware though that your progress bar is (== should be) updated by the windowing thread, and most things like button click event handlers are actioned by that same thread. This means that you click your button and the thread that created the progressbar gets busy doing your long running code...
Now, you're running your task async and this is good, just make sure that you await any lengthy operations so that the windowing thread can hand off to a background process at that point and go back to its main job (updating the UI) otherwise you won't see your progress bar updating very effectively. Don't try to update form controls from code that is run on a different thread to the main windowing thread. 
If you're not clear on how async/await works, visualise it that upon encountering `await` within some method block, the thread that is executing the code will create a background process to complete the await'd section, and it itself will travel back up the call stack til it reaches the first method not marked async and proceed from there. In practical terms in a windows forms app you want all your code that "does stuff" in response to a button click to be marked async so you can release the windowing thread out of your code context entirely and back to doing its job of keeping the UI responding, whenever you use await

An alternative way of doing this might be tonise a BackgroundWorker - you attach a DoWork event handler that does the work, and as part of this code it should regularly call the ReportProgress method, passing in an int percentage completion. The ProgressChanged event handler on the BGWorker is used to set the percentage bar/Uu elements -critically you need to know that DoWork runs on a thread that is NOT the windowing thread (and windows controls must not be accessed from a thread other than the thread that created them, usually the windowing thread) so we don't access the progress bar directly from DoWork- instead we call ReportProgress and that causes the ProgressChanged event to fire, and the BGWorker deliberately arranges things so the code in that event handler IS run on the windowing thread(actually the thread that creates the worker but this should be the same)